# Error - await is only valid in async function, when calling deployed on a truffle smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

Was following the [tutorial on the truffle website](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts). Did each step and setup as is. My `truffle compile` and `truffle migrate` work as intended. But when I try to do `let instance = await MetaCoin.deployed()` in truffle console, I get this error -

```
evalmachine.<anonymous>:1
let instance = await MetaCoin.deployed()
               ^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: Which version of truffle are you using? With truffle 5.1.22 and launching `truffle console` it works without using let.

Comment: I am using truffle@5.1.24. Removing `let` didn't do anything, but removing `await` worked. But for the very next command `let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()` I get the same error. Removing `await` there throws this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `MetaCoin` is not correctly defined defined
Make sure you are not missing one of these steps on you migration script
e.g.:

```
 const MetaCoin = artifacts.require("YourContractFilame")
 await deployer.deploy(MetaCoin)
 const deployedMetaCoinContract = await MetaCoin.deployed()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it  in async function and then  use .then() , .catch() to see if your contract is deployed...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that came across this error it looks like the async function was left as a regular function

```
module.exports = >async< function(deployer, network, accounts)
```

So since the async was left out when await was used it couldn't pair with the correct async function